# Why does this expression (-4 == 4'bzzzz) or (-4'sd4 == 4'bzzzz) returns '0' instead of unknown 'x'?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Why does this expression (-4 == 4'bzzzz) returns '0' instead of unknown 'x'?
Here's the link:
https://www.edaplayground.com/x/5zi_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing `c==z`. `c` is a 32-bit signed variable, and `z` is a 4-bit unsigned net which gets 0-extended to 32-bits. Since the upper bits of the comparison differ, the equality is unambiguously false.